# WPF toolbar's style not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I'm using a resource dictionary in my wpf proyect. 
The dictionary has these 2 styles:

```
<Style x:Key="MyMenu" TargetType="Menu">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MyToolbar" TargetType="ToolBar">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

And in my XAML file, I use these 2 styles as it follows:

For the menu:

```
<Menu Name="menuMainBar" Style="{DynamicResource MyMenu}" IsMainMenu="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <MenuItem ...
</Menu>
```

For the toolbar:

```
<ToolBarTray Name="toolBarTrayRigth_wargames"  Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <ToolBar Name="toolBarRigth_wargames" Style="{StaticResource MyToolbar}"  BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
                        <Button ...
            </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

This is the result:

[image: Menu style working, toolbar style not working]

As you can notice, the menu takes the style correctly, but the toolbar isn't affected by the style at all.

I tried removing all the style elements from the toolbartray tag, as it follows:

```
<ToolBarTray Name="toolBarTrayRigth_wargames">
        ...
</ToolBarTray>
```

And now the toolbar works, but as you can see, now the toolbarTray is not how I want it to be (I want a vertical toolbar, not a horizontal toolbar):

[image: Menu style working, toolbar style working, toolbartray not working]

I also tried setting the background of the ToolBar directly in the xaml file:

```
<ToolBarTray Name="toolBarTrayRigth_wargames"  Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <ToolBar Name="toolBarRigth_wargames" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"  Background="Black">
                        <Button ...
            </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

...and it works:

[image: Menu style working, toolbar style working, but not using the resource dictionary]

But I don't want to do that, I want to use a resource dictionary for my toolbar's style.

any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: if you load the resource-dictionary dynamicly (in run time), it could be because it is bound with `StaticResource`, instead `DynamicResource`

Comment: I tried both StaticResource and DynamicResource. Same problem with both.

Answer (score 1):

I found, bizarrely, that if I set the Orientation of the parent ToolBarTray to Horizontal, that your ToolBar style was able to set the background on the ToolBar.

I also found that with the ToolBarTray orientation still being Vertical, this worked to set the ToolBar's background:

```
<Style x:Key="MyToolbar" TargetType="ToolBar">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!-- 
        This is intentional. A conventional setter was found not to set the background 
        when the parent ToolBarTray's Orientation was Vertical. 
        -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Null}}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I find this very strange.

Answer (score 0):

as @EdPlunkett found, its a strange `Setter` in the default template in the `Trigger` for Vertical Orientation:

```
 <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
    <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Grid" Value="1,3,1,1"/>
    <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="OverflowButton">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFEEF5FD"/>
```

you can edit the template (in `Document Outline` panel, right click on the ToolBar element > Edit Template > Edit a Copy...), and remove this Setter.